# Video player thumbnail that plays in other page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have graphic animations on my site (over 200 and counting). The file formats are .ogv, .avi, .mov.

I have a summary page with all the video animations in thumbnail, and the user sees the HTML5 video player with each animation. Is it possible to keep the HTML5 video player with my animations on summary page, but when the user clicks the video, that then another page opens where the video can be played?

I know I can use thumbnail video image .png and have a "video play-button" image as watermark over it and link to the other page when click, but it's not the solution I want for over 200 videos. I tried hover-over effect, but when you click that then still the video plays immediately in the summary page.

Basically, I want the video player to show, but disable the controls. And allow clicking the video which leads the user to another page where full-screen video CAN be played. Is that possible?

This is my code:

```css
.videofile:hover {
  opacity:.3
}
```

```html
<div class="videofile">
  <video controls="">
    <source src="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AAnimaci%C3%B3n_de_escanciar.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't want the video to play, why have the controls at all?

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro - to show the users that it is a video instead of just an image. And video will be played once the user clicks through.

Comment: How about the solution I posted below? You could use `::before` or `::after` to cover the default controls and/or to remove the controls altogether and display a fake Play symbol

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - its perfect! Just tested it, exactly what I was after, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using the `::after` pseudo-element:

```css
.videofile {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.videofile:hover::after {
  content:"";
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
  <div class="videofile">
    <video controls="" preload="metadata">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
    </video>
  </div>
</a>
```

How this solution works:

- A link wraps the video container;
- An `::after` pseudo-element is added to the `div` containing the video. It will cover the whole area of its parent;
- The pseudo-element will only be displayed when the mouse hovers the video (that way the buttons will be covered and won't be clickable).

One good thing about this solution is that you can customize it with CSS: add pictures, text, or whatever you want in an easy way. For example, the code above was done to match the demo you posted as match as possible, but you could change it to display a Play button over the video without controls:

```css
.videofile {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.videofile:hover::after {
  content:"\25BA";
  font-size:64px;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  text-align:center;
  line-height:176px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <div class="videofile">
    <video preload="metadata">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
    </video>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Although it probably would just be easier to wrap the video in an `a` and remove the controls to avoid playing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. create image/picture thumbnails of videos:
2. Creates a link with a tag, and have the above images as content, similar to below:

   ```
   <a href="..." target="_blank"> <img ...  /> </a>
   ```

The _blank target takes you to the href url of a tag.

A sample example is on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pgmreddy/7n2ufv3o/)

Best of luck.

(Mark this as answer if this serves your need.)

Comment: I clearly mentioned that I did not want to create picture thumbnails because I have to do this manually for over 200 video files. Unless there is a way to automatically create those thumbnails???

Comment: Ok :).  #1 Note that www.youtube.com has images as thumbnails.    #2   Try this link for generating thumbnails from videos: https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_create_thumbnails/#How_to_create_a_thumbnail_from_a_video